# ¿Que significan los bytes antes de mi objeto?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Mi duda es que tengo este codigo el cual imprime memoria, pero no lo gro descifrar que signicado tienen los 8 bytes anteriores a los 4 bytes de mi objeto, y tampoco entiendo porque al hacer delete del p2 ni se inmuta su direccion de memoria, alguien que me puede ayudar?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>

void printRawMem(uint8_t* p, uint16_t linebytes, uint16_t lines) {
   for(uint16_t l=0; l < lines; ++l) {
      std::cout << reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(p) << " ";
      for(uint16_t u=0; u < linebytes; ++u) {
         [](uint16_t val) {
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << val;
         }(*p);
         ++p;
         std::cout << " ";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
}

struct pair {
   uint16_t x, y;
   pair(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) : x(x), y(y){
      std::cout << "Creating pair(" << x << " " << y << ") at (" << this << ", " << sizeof*this << " )\n";
   }
   ~pair() {
      std::cout << "Destroying pair\n";
   }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   pair *p = new pair(3,4);
   pair *p2 = new pair(2,7);
   uint8_t* ptr;
   ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p) - 16;
   printRawMem(ptr, 16, 4);
   std::cout << "--------------------------------------\n";
   delete p;
   delete p2;
   printRawMem(ptr, 16, 4);


   return 0;
}
```

Y tengo esta salida:

```
Creating pair(3 4) at (0x2582490, 4 )
Creating pair(2 7) at (0x25824b0, 4 )
0x2582480 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 70 f9 42 a2 b6 02 1c
0x2582490 03 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 dc 00 00 00 00 00
0x25824a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 70 f9 42 e1 a4 02 1c
0x25824b0 02 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 dc 00 00 00 00 00
--------------------------------------
Destroying pair
Destroying pair
0x2582480 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a3 71 f8 f4 a2 b6 02 00
0x2582490 a0 63 dc 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 dc 00 00 00 00 00
0x25824a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 01 03 e1 a4 02 1c
0x25824b0 02 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 dc 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `new` funciona de forma similar al `malloc()` del C estándar (de hecho, no estoy seguro de que en realidad no esté implementado llamando a `malloc()`)

Ambos usan una zona de memoria del proceso llamada el *heap* para obtener la memoria necesaria para los nuevos objetos.

El *heap* debe ir llevando la cuenta de qué zonas ya han sido asignadas a otras variables y cuáles no. Básicamente cuando haces `malloc(4)` estás solicitando que te busque 4 bytes consecutivos libres. En C++ cuando haces `new pair(3,4)` básicamente ocurre lo mismo, sólo que el compilador calcula el número de bytes necesarios, los reserva en el *heap* y luego llama al constructor del objeto (pasándole en `this` la dirección obtenida, `0x2582490` en este caso) para que inicialice el objeto.

Las funciones que manejan el *heap* tienen que marcar que los 4 bytes que comienzan en la dirección `0x2582490` están "ocupados", para que el siguiente `new` no los use. Estas funciones además tienen que tener algún mecanismo eficiente para encontrar rápidamente zonas libres en el *heap*. Por ejemplo, podría guardar una lista enlazada con las direcciones y tamaños de cada trozo libre en el *heap*. La forma en que se hace esto es dependiente de la implementación, pero generalmente se usa *el propio heap* para almacenar estas estructuras de datos.

Por tanto, podemos conjeturar que lo que estás viendo delante de tus datos, son los *metadatos* que las funciones de manejo del *heap* están guardando allí para gestionar qué zonas están libres y cuáles ocupadas, sus direcciones, tamaños, etc.

Cuando haces un `del` (o un `free()` en C estándar), lo único que ocurre es que las funciones que manejan el *heap* modifican los metadatos para indicar que una zona antes ocupada ahora está libre. No tienen por qué borrar esa zona (de hecho en tu caso se ve que el 2 y el 7 siguen estando allí), ni por qué modificar el puntero que apuntaba a ellas. Simplemente ese puntero ya no debe usarse porque estaría apuntando a una zona "basura".

Comment: Gracias sabia eso pero en posix habia visto que justamente tenia en los 4bytes anteriores la suma de mis 4bytes(del pair) mas los 4 bytes del siguiente bloque mas uno. Este ultimo supuse que era algun tipo de flag del sistema ya que siempre se almacenan numero par de memoria. Pero gracias osea que lo de antes solo es informacion para la estructura de arbol del heap, no?